# How to setup Castle.WindsorContainer not to wrap known exception on resolve

Tags: c#, exception, castle-windsor

I use castle to resolve dependencies through constructor injection.
My problem is that the constructor for a service might use 3rd party plugin code.
If this plugin code throws an exception, it is wrapped in a known exception, say "KnownException".

I have a special exception policy to log and handle the "KnownException". 
The problem is that if the Castle Windsorcontainer resolve encounters an exception it is wrapped in a 'Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.ComponentActivatorException'.

Is there a way to avoid this, and just let the 'KnownException' propagate?

A simple scenario:

```
public class KnownException : Exception
{

}

// registerd in castle
public class DetailViewModel
{
    public DetailViewModel(Selector thirdPartySelector)
    {
        thirdPartySelector.GetElements(); // might throw known exception
    }
}

// registered as TypedFactory in Castle
public interface IViewModelFactory
{

    DetailViewModel Create(Selector thirdPartySelector);
}


public class MasterViewModel
{
    private readonly IViewModelFactory viewModelFactory;
    private readonly Selector selector;

    public MasterViewModel(IViewModelFactory viewModelFactory)
    {
        this.viewModelFactory = viewModelFactory;
        selector = Mock.Of<Selector>();  // for illustration purpose only. Creation is more elaborate, and not relly a problem here.
    }


    public void OnAddDetailed()
    {
        try
        {
            var vm = viewModelFactory.Create(selector);

            // adding detailed view model.

        }
        catch (KnownException e)
        {
            // Log and continue
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you show us some code? How do you resolve the third party plugin? Factory method?

Comment: We have very strict policy in the company about sharing code. I can provide mock code, but it really isn't that complex.The 3rd party code is provided as parameter through a TypedFactory argument. The argument is used to populate the resolved object in the constructor.

Comment: I understand, however without some example of what you're observing and what you're expecting it's hard helping you. If the mock is really not that complex you should be able to whip a working example quite quickly

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `ComponentActivatorException` wraps the initial exception before being thrown when Castle tries to resolve the component. There is no way to bypass this behavior.

Your best bet would be to catch the `ComponentActivatorException` and throw its `InnerException` in order to find again a known type for your error handling

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that. The inner exception is actually a TargetInvocationException, which again holds my KnownException. Currently I solved this particular problem by separating creation and population, I not completely happy with that, as it is kind of brittle. All constructors that might throw need to be tested separately to make sure construction and population is separated.

Comment: It looks like there are some specifics about your plugin that may alter the answer to match them more accurately. Have you considered showing us an imaginary example?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid castle using the component activator, you can register your component with a `UsingFactoryMethod` ie:

```
Component.For<IFoo>().UsingFactoryMethod(k => new Foo())
```

There are some drawbacks:
If `Foo` has dependencies you will need to resolve these from the container yourself, and interceptors won't work. If needed `OnDestroy` can help with releasing the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by decorating the factory, catch the ComponentActivatorException and throw the InnerException. 
But I'm wondering, if this should be solved by the container, as if I'm using the factory, I should not be aware there is a container outside. But if the create method throws a CastleWindsor Exception, that is not the case.

My solution:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CastleWindsor_FactoryThrows_MyException()
{
    WindsorContainer Container = new WindsorContainer();

    Container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

    Container.Register(Component.For<IMyFactory>().ImplementedBy<MyFactoryDecorator>());
    Container.Register(Component.For<IMyFactory>().AsFactory());
    Container.Register(Component.For<MyClass>().LifestyleTransient());

    var factory = Container.Resolve<IMyFactory>();

    try
    {
        factory.Create();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(e.GetType(), typeof(MyException));
    }
}

public class MyFactoryDecorator : IMyFactory
{
    IMyFactory factory;

    public MyFactoryDecorator(IMyFactory aFactory)
    {
        factory = aFactory;
    }

    MyClass IMyFactory.Create() => handleComponentActivatorException(() => factory.Create());


    T handleComponentActivatorException<T>(Func<T> action)
    {
        try
        {
            return action();
        }
        catch (ComponentActivatorException e)
        {
            throw e.InnerException.InnerException;
        }
    }
}

public interface IMyFactory
{
    MyClass Create();
}

public class MyException : Exception { }

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        throw new MyException();
    }
}
```